# Multipole expansion of $V$ in powers of $\frac{1}{r}$

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

If the total charge is $0$, why should the dominant term be the dipole? Also, for a dipole consisting of only two opposite charges separated by a distance $d$, i dont understand how can there be higher multipole contributions(since there are only two charges)?

Comment: You need to explain what assumptions on $V$ you are making here and what exactly you mean by "dominant term".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the multipole expansion:

$$ V({\bf r}) = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0r}\int_{V'}\rho({\bf r'})\big(
1-\frac{\bf \hat r\cdot r}{r}+\frac{1}{2r^2}(3({\bf \hat r\cdot r})^2-r'^2)+O(\frac{r'}r)^3
\big)d{\bf r'}$$

if the total charge is 0, then the "$1$" (monopole) term integrates to zero, leaving the next term: the dipole term:

$$ V_{\rm dip}({\bf r}) = -\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}\int_{V'}\rho({\bf r'})(
\bf \hat r\cdot r'
)d{\bf r'}$$

as the leading term, by definition. It falls of as $1/r^2$, and all the other terms fall off as higher powers of $1/r$.

Opposite charges in a dipole configuration:

$$ \rho({\bf r}) = \frac 1 2 qd[\delta({\bf \hat z})-\delta({-\bf \hat z})] $$

form an approximate dipole. A true dipole is the limit as $d \rightarrow 0$, with $qd$ remaining fixed. The quadrupole moment is:

$$ V_{\rm quad}({\bf r}) \equiv \frac 1 {8\pi\epsilon_0r^3}
\int_{V'} \rho({\bf r'})\big(3({\bf \hat r\cdot r'})^2-r'^2 \big)d{\bf r'}]$$

$$ V_{\rm quad}({\bf r})= \frac {qd} {16\pi\epsilon_0r^3}[(3z^2-1^2)-(3(-z)^2-(-1)^2)]=0$$

which is required by symmetry: dipoles are odd and quadrupoles are even.

The octupole moment is odd, and goes like:

$$ V_{\rm oct} \propto \frac 1 {r^4} \int_{V'} ({\bf \hat r \cdot r'})(5({\bf \hat r \cdot r'}^2)-3r'^2)d{\bf r'} \propto \frac {qd^3} {r^4}(5z^3-3z)$$

which is non zero. Note that for $r >> d$ it is negligible, and in the dipole limit ($d \rightarrow 0$) with:

$$ qd \rightarrow \mu $$

$$ qd^3 \rightarrow 0$$

it *is* zero.

Comment: Can you explain the physical meaning of octupole contribution to this configuration? Why does it even arise?

Comment: And can you explain how you got the equation of dipole configuration?

Comment: the 2 delta functions with oppose sign are 2 opposite point charges. 2 charges only form a pure dipole in the limit $d \rightarrow 0$. If $d$ is finite, then they have a non-zero projection on all odd spherical harmonics, meaning they have all odd multipole moments. Think about $d = 1,000$ light years. You're just not going to have a pure dipole field near one of the charges. What does that mean? It means you need higher moments to account for the field. Physically, it means the field isn't a pure dipole, that's it.

Comment: what is it about the finite distance between the charges that produces this higher pole contribution? Why is there a difference in the field just because they are separated?

Comment: is it a consequence of the superposition theorem?

Comment: for a true dipole shouldn't the octupole moment be exactly zero?